# Quando uma função é executada um novo objeto thread é criado?

Tags: lua

De acordo com o [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) da versão 5.3, um valor do tipo thread representa tópicos independentes de execução:

> The type thread represents independent threads of execution and it is used to implement coroutines (see §2.6). Lua threads are not related to operating-system threads.

Isso significa que toda vez que o corpo/escopo de uma função é executado um novo thread é criado? Ou isso acontece com todo tipo de escopo? Por exemplo:

```
-- Cria um thread (principal)

(function()
    -- Cria um thread
    for i = 1, 2 do
        -- Cria outro thread
    end
end)();
```

Ou com funções apenas:

```
-- Cria um thread (principal)

(function()
    -- Cria um thread
    for i = 1, 2 do
    end
end)();
```

Comment: Não entendi de onde você tirou essa sua interpretação. "O Tipo `thread` representa thread de execução independentes e é usada para implementar `coroutines`. O que você quer dizer com bloco? Um `if`, um `loop`? Se for, isso é questão de escopo da linguagem.

Comment: @Gerep Quando me refiro à bloco me refiro à uma lista de statements (um statement é uma instrução que não é uma expressão)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pergunta**: isso significa que toda vez que o corpo/escopo de uma função é executado uma nova thread é criada ?
**Resposta**: não.

**Pergunta**: ou isso acontece com todo tipo de escopo ?
**Resposta**: não.

**Explicação**: Uma "thread" (quando se fala da linguagem Lua) é criada apenas quando se cria uma co-rotina (*coroutine*) através da funções *coroutine.create* e *coroutine.wrap*.

Referência: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.11

Exemplo de uso: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_coroutines.htm

A propósito, acho que este estilo de codificação:

```
(function()
   -- Cria um thread
   for i = 1, 2 do
       -- Cria outro thread
   end
end)();
```

que é bastante comum em JavaScript normalmente não é utilizado com Lua.

Comment: Em relação ao estilo de codificação, eu só queria tentar exemplar minha dúvida às funções. Eu poderia ter não usado uma função, e sim um do, ou nem precisava do do, mas minha dúvida é mais ligada à funções também. Eu estava começando à pensar que o thread seria uma referência aos statements que estão sendo atualmente executados numa lista de statements / ou função.

Comment: pra dizer a verdade nem sei se esse tipo de codificação é aceito, não testei mas desconfio que não

Comment: Ele é válido, mas funções expressadas não podem especificar nome ou nome de membros, e funções locais só podem especificar nomes: `local function a() end`, `function a:x() end function a.y() end function b() end`. Já o semicolon, pelo que eu saiba sempre foi suportado, mas em alguma versão do Lua ele parece ser mal-interpretado. O luaparse que eu conheço não deixa o semicolon ser um statement quando ele não delimita statements.

Comment: você tem razão, testei aqui e funcionou